# How do I run the printf command on a Windows 10 PC that uses Linux Containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have come across this Helm chart for SQL Server 2017: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mssql-linux

It looks very useful.  So I have followed the instructions:

1. `helm install --name mymssql stable/mssql-linux --set acceptEula.value=Y --set edition.value=Developer`

   This works as expected i.e. the `kubectl` commands below it return the expected results.  It then says:
2. `printf $(kubectl get secret --namespace default mymssql-mssql-linux-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.sapassword}" | base64 --decode);echo`

I have run this in a command prompt and in Powershell and it just says printf is not recognised (as I expected).  How do I run the printf command on a Windows 10 PC that uses Linux Containers?

I have spent time Googling it, which tells me that printf is a C++ function.  How do I follow step 2?

Comment: That's actually a buggy use of printf -- someone using it as-intended isn't supposed to put data in the format-string field.

Comment: ...so, the question is *why* printf is being used there. One possibility is that the intent is to expand backslash-escape sequences inside the password being extracted -- if you don't have any, you might be able to just ignore it and only worry about translating the rest of the command. Another possibility is that it's being used as a rather expensive and side-effecting way to strip the newline.

Comment: (There shouldn't be any backslash-escape sequences in base64-encoded content!)

Comment: @Charles Duffy, How do I get the sa password? I can then expose the pod and connect to it using SQL Studio Manager.

Comment: ...btw, the *right* way to use printf to expand escape sequences is to use `printf '%b' "$(...code to generate content with sequences here...)"`, making it instead `'%b\n'` if a trailing newline is intended.

Comment: The password is still emitted (albeit in base64-encoded form) by the inner `kubectl get-secret` command, right? If that's the case, you just need to figure out how to decode base64 data in Powershell.

Comment: (To be very clear, I'm over here as someone who groks the UNIX-y side of things, but isn't willing to admit to any Windows experience/knowledge in public).

Comment: @Charles Duffy, is printf specific to Linux/Unix?

Comment: There's a `printf` call in C that's standard everywhere, but as a standalone command, it's a POSIX-family-shell thing; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Comment: Is there a way to get the SA password from the link I provided (on a windows PC that uses Linux containers)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211235/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-w0051977).

Comment: are you able to use chat? I've added some further explanation there I'd rather not need to rewrite/mirror.

Comment: #2 looks like a shell script written by a windows person : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required data is printed by the `kubectl` command within the `$()`.

The base 64 decoding can be done within `kubectl` itself via Go templates rather than piping the `kubectl` output into `base64` (which probably doesn't exist on windows without [mssys](https://www.msys2.org/) installed)

```
kubectl get secret mymssql-mssql-linux-secret -o go-template='{{.data.sapassword | base64decode}}'
```

The `printf`/`echo` additions in the example command seem redundant, or at least a bad way to get a newline after the output.  If you find you need a new line to be added on the end of the output on Windows, use the following template

```
'{{.data.sapassword | base64decode}}{{ "\n" }}'
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my question here (it is similar): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61145999/rabbitmq-pod-web-username-and-password/61146377?noredirect=1#comment108174649_61146377.  Please see the last sentence of the question.