# RabbitMQ pod web username and password?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I am trying to learn more about Kubernetes in my spare time.

At the moment I am trying to setup RabbitMQ, so I went here: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/RabbitMQ.  I have done this:

```
helm install my-release --set rabbitmq.username=admin,rabbitmq.password=secretpassword,rabbitmq.erlangCookie=secretcookie bitnami/rabbitmq
```

then:

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/my-release-rabbitmq 15672:15672
```

I can then browse to http://localhost:15672/

Powershell says this:

[image]

I am interested in this (from Poweshell):

```
echo "Password      : $(kubectl get secret --namespace default my-release-rabbitmq -o jsonpath="{.data.rabbitmq-password}" | base64 --decode)"
```

How do I get the password?

Comment: check the configmap and secret used by the release on the kubernetes cluster. Usualy they placed user and password there

Comment: @Fauzan, I have tried this: kubectl get secret my-release-RabbitMQ.  Can you post a command in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me:

1)     `helm install release --set rabbitmq.username=admin,rabbitmq.password=secretpassword,rabbitmq.erlangCookie=secretcookie bitnami/rabbitmq`

2) `kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/my-release-rabbitmq 15672:15672`

3) browse to: `localhost:15672`

4) login as: `admin/secretpassword`

I am using Helm 3 so I had to say: `helm install release` instead of just `helm install` i.e. I had to specify a name.

Also note that I had to change the name to release instead of my-release as it does not like the dash (in step 1 and step 2).  I am using Windows (Docker for Windows with Linux containers if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 2):

You can find instructions for setting your username/password at the bottom of this [readme](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq#parameters).

```
helm install rabbitmq \
  --set rabbitmq.username=admin,rabbitmq.password=secretpassword,rabbitmq.erlangCookie=secretcookie \
    bitnami/rabbitmq
```

Comment: could you post a screenshot or post the values?

Comment: That command errors: Error: expected at most two arguments, unexpected arguments: \, bitnami/rabbitmq

Comment: I'll add the command to my answer, I think the comment formatting is disrupting it's syntax

Comment: That does not work: '--set' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I'm getting a different error when trying to use this command, I've solved it though, try to run the command now, after I've edited my answer one more time.

Comment: sorry it just s does not work.  Why are the commands on multiple lines?

Comment: It can work as a single line command as well, here's an example - `helm install --set rabbitmq.username=admin,rabbitmq.password=secretpassword,rabbitmq.erlangCookie=secretcookie bitnami/rabbitmq`

Comment: Please see the last screenshot of my question.  It does not work.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211388/discussion-between-yaron-idan-and-w0051977).

Comment: Which helm version are you using? I suspect this is the main issue here.

Comment: you are missing a name for the helm deployment, add --generate-name or rabbitmq

Comment: @paltaa, you're right. I've used the helm2 syntax which generates a name by default. I've fixed that to fit helm 3 syntax because that is what OP is using.

Comment: yep, had that issues before with helm hehe